# Отправка из формы значения только выбранного select'a

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

В форме есть два селекта. При появлении одного - второй скрывается. Пользователь может выбрать значение только одного селекта. Потом средствами Ajax значения передаются в PHP обработчик. Но проблема в том, что всегда передается значение последнего селекта. Как это исправить?

```js
$('.reg').hide();
$('#yandexUA').change(function() {
    $('#ua').toggle();
    $('#ua [value="187"]').attr('selected', 'true');
    $('#ru [value="225"]').attr('selected', 'false');
    $('#ru').hide();
});
$('#yandexRU').change(function() {
    $('#ru').toggle();
    $('#ru [value="225"]').attr('selected', 'true');
    $('#ua [value="187"]').attr('selected', 'false');
    $('#ua').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="val" method="post" action="val.php" id="form">
                    
                        <div class="col">

                            <h4>Выберите регион поиска Яндекс</h4>
                            <div class="form-check mb-2 ">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="yandex" id="yandexUA"
                                       value="339">
                                <label class="form-check-label mr-3" for="yandexUA">
                                    Украина
                                </label>
                                <div id="ua" class="input-group reg">

                                    <select class="custom-select" id="selectUA" name="yandex_region">
                                        <option value="187">Вся Украина</option>
                                        <option value="20544">Киевская область</option>
                                        <option value="20549">Полтавская область</option>
                                        <option value="20546">Черкасская область</option>
                                        <option value="20545">Винницкая область</option>
                                        <option value="20548">Кировоградская область</option>
                                        <option value="20547">Житомирская область</option>
                                        <option value="20538">Харьковская область</option>
                                        <option value="20536"> Донецкая область</option>
                                        <option value="20537"> Днепропетровская область</option>
                                        <option value="20540"> Луганская область</option>
                                        <option value="20539"> Запорожская область</option>
                                        <option value="20541"> Одесская область</option>
                                        <option value="20543"> Николаевская область</option>
                                        <option value="20542"> Херсонская область</option>
                                        <option value="20529"> Львовская область</option>
                                        <option value="20535"> Хмельницкая область</option>
                                        <option value="20531"> Тернопольская область</option>
                                        <option value="20534"> Ровенская область</option>
                                        <option value="20533"> Черновицкая область</option>
                                        <option value="20550"> Волынская область</option>
                                        <option value="20530"> Закарпатская область</option>
                                        <option value="20532"> Ивано-Франковская область</option>
                                        <option value="20552"> Сумская область</option>
                                        <option value="20551"> Черниговская область</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check mb-2 ">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="yandex" id="yandexRU"
                                       value="412">
                                <label class="form-check-label mr-3" for="yandexRU">
                                    Россия
                                </label>
                                <div id="ru" class="input-group reg">

                                    <select class="custom-select" id="selectRU" name="yandex_region">
                                        <option value="225">Вся Россия</option>
                                        <option value="20"> Архангельск</option>
                                        <option value="37"> Астрахань</option>
                                        <option value="197"> Барнаул</option>
                                        <option value="4"> Белгород</option>
                                        <option value="77"> Благовещенск</option>
                                        <option value="191"> Брянск</option>
                                        <option value="24"> Великий Новгород</option>
                                        <option value="75"> Владивосток</option>
                                        <option value="33"> Владикавказ</option>
                                        <option value="192"> Владимир</option>
                                        <option value="38"> Волгоград</option>
                                        <option value="21"> Вологда</option>
                                        <option value="193"> Воронеж</option>
                                        <option value="1106"> Грозный</option>
                                        <option value="54"> Екатеринбург</option>
                                        <option value="5"> Иваново</option>
                                        <option value="63"> Иркутск</option>
                                        <option value="41"> Йошкар-Ола</option>
                                        <option value="43"> Казань</option>
                                        <option value="22"> Калининград</option>
                                        <option value="64"> Кемерово</option>
                                        <option value="7"> Кострома</option>
                                        <option value="35"> Краснодар</option>
                                        <option value="62"> Красноярск</option>
                                        <option value="53"> Курган</option>
                                        <option value="8"> Курск</option>
                                        <option value="9"> Липецк</option>
                                        <option value="28"> Махачкала</option>
                                        <option value="1"> Москва и Московская область</option>
                                        <option value="213"> Москва</option>
                                        <option value="23"> Мурманск</option>
                                        <option value="1092"> Назрань</option>
                                        <option value="30"> Нальчик</option>
                                        <option value="47"> Нижний Новгород</option>
                                        <option value="65"> Новосибирск</option>
                                        <option value="66"> Омск</option>
                                        <option value="10"> Орел</option>
                                        <option value="48"> Оренбург</option>
                                        <option value="49"> Пенза</option>
                                        <option value="50"> Пермь</option>
                                        <option value="25"> Псков</option>
                                        <option value="39"> Ростов-на-Дону</option>
                                        <option value="11"> Рязань</option>
                                        <option value="51"> Самара</option>
                                        <option value="2"> Санкт-Петербург</option>
                                        <option value="42"> Саранск</option>
                                        <option value="12"> Смоленск</option>
                                        <option value="239"> Сочи</option>
                                        <option value="36"> Ставрополь</option>
                                        <option value="973"> Сургут</option>
                                        <option value="13"> Тамбов</option>
                                        <option value="14"> Тверь</option>
                                        <option value="67"> Томск</option>
                                        <option value="15"> Тула</option>
                                        <option value="195"> Ульяновск</option>
                                        <option value="172"> Уфа</option>
                                        <option value="76"> Хабаровск</option>
                                        <option value="45"> Чебоксары</option>
                                        <option value="56"> Челябинск</option>
                                        <option value="1104"> Черкесск</option>
                                        <option value="16"> Ярославль</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label ">Запрос №1</label>
                            <input type="text" name="query1" class="form-control" id="query1"
                                   placeholder="Например, Рога и копыта" autofocus required>
                            <small id="help" class="form-text text-danger font-italic "></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn_wrap">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary plus ">&#10010;</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Сформировать отчет</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Например, убирать `name` у скрытого `select`-a. А ещё `attr('selected', 'true')` - категорически неправильно. В данном случае вообще достаточно `$('#selectUA').val(187)`

Comment: Спасибо! сделал как вы написали. убираю name и все работает)

Comment: конечно! давайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отправлялось значение только одного из select-ов, у второго должно отсутствовать значение атрибута `name`. Поэтому кроме скрытия/показа select-ов нужно ещё добавлять/удалять `name` у них:

```js
$(".reg").hide();

$("#yandexUA").on("change", function() {
  $("#ua").show();
  $("#selectUA").val(187).attr("name", "yandex_region");
  $("#ru").hide();
  $("#selectRU").removeAttr("name");
});

$("#yandexRU").on("change", function() {
  $("#ru").show();
  $("#selectRU").val(225).attr("name", "yandex_region");
  $("#ua").hide();
  $("#selectUA").removeAttr("name");
});

//для наглядности
$("form").on("submit", function() {
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form name="val" method="post" action="val.php" id="form">
  <div class="col">
    <h4>Выберите регион поиска Яндекс</h4>
    <div class="form-check mb-2 ">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="yandex" id="yandexUA" value="339">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-3" for="yandexUA">
        Украина
      </label>
      <div id="ua" class="input-group reg">
        <select class="custom-select" id="selectUA" name="yandex_region">
          <option value="187">Вся Украина</option>
          <option value="20544">Киевская область</option>
          <option value="20549">Полтавская область</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-2 ">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="yandex" id="yandexRU" value="412">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-3" for="yandexRU">
        Россия
      </label>
      <div id="ru" class="input-group reg">
        <select class="custom-select" id="selectRU" name="yandex_region">
          <option value="225">Вся Россия</option>
          <option value="20"> Архангельск</option>
          <option value="37"> Астрахань</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Запрос №1</label>
      <input type="text " name="query1 " class="form-control " id="query1 " placeholder="Например, Рога и копыта " autofocus required>
      <small id="help " class="form-text text-danger font-italic "></small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_wrap ">
    <button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary " id="submit ">Сформировать отчет</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```